# Displaying merged cell data in a For loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to display the contents of a merged cell in a `For` loop in Excel using VBA.

I have the a worksheet with very simple data in it

[image: initial list]

Here is my code:

```
'finding last record in my initial list    
sheet_last_row = Sheets("mylist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To sheet_last_row
    last_row = Sheets("results").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If Sheets("mylist").Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
        'test if cell is merged
        If Sheets("mylist").Cells(i, 2).MergeCells Then
            RowCount = Sheets("mylist").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
        Sheets("mylist").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("results").Cells(last_row + 1, 1)
    End If
Next i
```

I'm getting the following result with this code;

[image: results]

I'm new at this. Can anyone show me how to make this work.

Comment: Could you post an image of  the desired result?

Comment: FYI - in most cases, merging cells in considered bad practice for reasons exactly like this, *among others*. I would reconsider if you actually need to merge cells in the first place.

Comment: What is this **RowCount** variable used for? What exactly are you trying to do with **MergeCells** and after it? BTW the cell **Sarah** is in, is actually cell **B5**, so if you would loop through the range and skip empty cells (the cells in range **B6:B9** are 'treated' as empty), you would get a proper result. I don't think that it is so easy, so you'll have to better explain what to do when a merged cell is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB, LastRowC As Long, LastRowE As Long, MaxRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find the lastrow for all the available columns
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'Get the longer last row in order to avoid losing data if the last cell of a column is merge or empty
        MaxRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(LastRowA, LastRowB, LastRowC)

        'Set the area to loop
        Set rng = .Range("A2:C" & MaxRow)

        'Start looping
        For Each cell In rng

            'If the cell is merger
            If cell.MergeCells Then

                'Find the last row of column E
                LastRowE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

                'Paste cell value in column E
                .Range("E" & LastRowE + 1).Value = cell.Value
                'Paste cell address in column F
                .Range("F" & LastRowE + 1).Value = cell.Address

            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]